# the command node bin\www results in module not found error

Tags: node.js

I am currently learning how to use nodejs alongside with express as well as ejs. I have a sample app.js file below

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

As well as corresponding index.js files in a routes folder in the same directory as app.js. Below is the index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have already installed the missing packages by running npm install within the App folder that holds app.js, routes, views as well as other various folders. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Some stacktrace and what you are trying to run/do would be nice.

Comment: From what I see, you are using [`express-generator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator) to create the boilerplate for you, in which case it should work as expected after running `npm install` followed by `node ./bin/www` or `npm start`. I just tested this right now and there is nothing wrong with `express-generator`. In the event where this code was from a tutorial where it had to be written by hand, then the issue might be more complex as the bug may lie anywhere ( ** the stacktrace would greatly help**). Can you provide us with the stacktrace to further troubleshoot?

Comment: @JKleinne the problem has been resolved. i unistalled node and reinstalled in and now i seems to be deploying fine. Thank you!!